# MySQL Get Matching Results From two queries?

Tags: php, mysql

I have some php code that generates multiple MySql queries and combines the results.
I am trying to find a way to combine the queries so the only fields that match in both queries are outputed.

Example of PHP Codes Output.

```
SELECT LoadData_3 pow FROM tblLoadData WHERE LoadData_1 = 'test1' AND LoadData_2 = 'test2' 
UNION ALL
SELECT LoadData_3 pow FROM tblLoadData WHERE LoadData_1 = 'test3' AND LoadData_2 = 'test4'
```

I want only the LoadData_3 fields that are the same in both queries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `INTERSECT` operation:

```
(SELECT LoadData_3 pow 
  FROM tblLoadData 
 WHERE LoadData_1 = 'test1' 
   AND LoadData_2 = 'test2')
INTERSECT                     -- return the intersection of the two queries
(SELECT LoadData_3 pow 
  FROM tblLoadData 
 WHERE LoadData_1 = 'test3' 
   AND LoadData_2 = 'test4')
```

**EDIT**

For MySQL you can use `INNER JOIN USING (..)`

```
SELECT pow -- Use DISTINCT pow instead if you want unique values (like INTERSECT)
  FROM (SELECT LoadData_3 pow 
          FROM tblLoadData 
         WHERE LoadData_1 = 'test1' 
           AND LoadData_2 = 'test2') T1
  INNER JOIN
       (SELECT LoadData_3 pow 
          FROM tblLoadData 
         WHERE LoadData_1 = 'test3' 
           AND LoadData_2 = 'test4') T2
  USING (pow)
```

Or using a WHERE IN clause:

```
SELECT LoadData_3 pow -- Use DISTINCT pow instead if you want unique values (like INTERSECT)
  FROM tblLoadData 
 WHERE LoadData_1 = 'test1' 
   AND LoadData_2 = 'test2'
   AND LoadData_3 IN (SELECT LoadData_3 pow 
                        FROM tblLoadData 
                       WHERE LoadData_1 = 'test3' 
                         AND LoadData_2 = 'test4')
```

Comment: Ok when I try doing an intersect I receive an error.
Is this something to do with my code?

SELECT LoadData_Powder pow FROM tblLoadData WHERE LoadData_Case = '308 Winchester' AND LoadData_Bullet = '#3039 FTX' 
INTERSECT 
SELECT LoadData_Powder pow FROM tblLoadData WHERE LoadData_Case = '30-30 Winchester' AND LoadData_Bullet = '#3039 FTX'

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTERSECT SELECT LoadData_Powder FROM tblLoadData WHERE LoadData_Case = '30-30 W' at line 2

Comment: I believe intersect may be SQL only

Comment: MySQL doesn't have `INTERSECT`

Comment: @Talon06, yeah. It appears that way.  Anyway, for MySQL you can use INNER JOIN USING(..)  or do a SELECT FROM and use a WHERE IN clause to filter (See my edited response)

Comment: Thanks for posting the Inner Join Example that got me on my way.

Answer (score 2):

Big Edit!

I've spent too much time in Oracle, and I skimmed over that article too quickly! The above answer was edited before mine. You can also take a look at the following question:

[Alternative to Intersect in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621382/intersect-in-mysql)

Comment: The article describes an alternative to MySQL (right below your code it says `can be rewritten as...`) as MySQL doesn't support `INTERSECT`