# Why is this SQL giving a syntax error?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Trying to see what video categories "me_id" and "you_id" have both watched with:

```sql
SELECT c.title, COUNT(*) AS popularity 
FROM video v 
JOIN user u ON v.user_id = u.id 
JOIN v_cat vc ON c.id = vc.vid_id 
JOIN cat c ON c.id = vc.cat_id
JOIN u_cat uc ON uc.cat_id = c.id  
WHERE uc.user_id = '$me_id'

INTSERSECT 

SELECT c.title, COUNT(*) AS popularity 
FROM video v 
JOIN user u ON v.user_id = u.id 
JOIN v_cat vc ON c.id = vc.vid_id 
JOIN cat c ON c.id = vc.cat_id
JOIN u_cat uc ON uc.cat_id = c.id  
WHERE uc.user_id = '$you_id'

GROUP BY c.title 
ORDER BY uc.id DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

I am working with PHP/MYSQL any thoughts?

Comment: print the query and show us so we can observ and find the mistake

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[MySQL doesn't have `INTERSECT`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621382/intersect-in-mysql)

Comment: +1 That's the second problem. You're way ahead of us! :)

Answer (score 0):

JOIN  JOIN  , Is that valid syntax?

Answer (score 0):

FROM video v JOIN  JOIN v_cat vc ON c.id = vc.vid_id

in the above line u have to use join one time..

Answer (score 0):

I see two consecutive JOIN keywords in your first select but without any error message this is going to be difficult to debug.

Comment: this was a typo...fixed in the question..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of INTERSECT, you can use the key word UNION or UNION ALL, this basically will do the intersection select. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html