# How to merge two mysql queries efficiently to return matching records?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am being rather stupid (!) but can't quite work out the best way to write a query for mysql and thought i'd post it on here to see if someone can help (fyi i'm using PHP). I have 5 tables:

```
TUsers (ID, Name) 
TJobTypes (ID, Name) 
TJobs (ID, JobTypeID, JobName) 
TJobsRequested (ID, JobID, UserID) 
TJobsOffered (ID, JobID, UserID)
```

FYI TJobsTypes to TJobs is a one to many relationship.

Users can search for job swaps based on jobs they can do and jobs that are needed/offered. So if User1 searches and says he needs 'JobA' doing and can offer 'JobB' and User2 is listed as needing 'JobB' doing and can offer 'JobA' then this would be a match. If User2 needs JobB doing but cannot offer JobA then it is not a match. It is easy enough to write a query to match this correctly, however users also need to be able to search based on general job type (as opposed to specific jobs).

So if UserA is searching for: 'needs JobTypeA' and 'can offer JobTypeB' then the matches should be all users who have a joboffered within the JobTypeA category and has a jobrequested in the JobTypeB category (if that makes sense!)

If you are just searching one way round (eg show all users who are listed as needing a job within JobType=$typecanhelp) then this is quite easy and can be done similar to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TUsers.Fid, TUsers.FUsername, TUsers.FGender 
FROM TUsers, TJobsRequested, TJobs, TJobTypes 
WHERE TJobTypes.Fid='$typecanhelp' 
AND TJobs.FJobTypeID=TJobTypes.Fid 
AND TJobs.Fid=TJobsRequested.FJobID 
AND TUsers.Fid=TJobsRequested.FUserID 
ORDER BY TUsers.Fid
```

OR (for showing all users who are listed as offering a job with JobType=$typeneedhelp):

```
SELECT DISTINCT TUsers.Fid, TUsers.FUsername, TUsers.FGender 
FROM TUsers, TJobsOffered, TJobs, TJobTypes 
WHERE TJobTypes.Fid='$typeneedhelp' 
AND TJobs.FJobTypeID=TJobTypes.Fid 
AND TJobs.Fid=TJobsOffered.FJobID 
AND TUsers.Fid=TJobsOffered.FUserID 
ORDER BY TUsers.Fid
```

I can't however work out how to merge the two together as they are using the same base tables (TJobs and TJobTypes). Could someone point me in the right direction as to how to merge the above two queries so it returns users that are offering a job with JobType==$jobcanhelp and need jobs doing with JobType=$jobsneedhelp?

Comment: I count 5 tables, not 4.

Comment: Does mysql support (nonrecursive) CTE's ?

Comment: @SalmanA: You are correct i put 4 instead of 5, i have updated this :)

Comment: @wildplasser I don't believe mysql supports CTEs, this has to be done via views in mysql.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly you are wanting to do a [INTERSECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) which I don't think is supported by mysql. It appears you can use INNER JOIN to accomplish the same with mysql. Take a look at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621382/intersect-in-mysql) or [this page](http://www.bitbybit.dk/carsten/blog/?p=71) for more information.

Comment: Will that not just list the results of both queries in one result set rather than actually only returning results that match both (ie users who have a matching jobrequest AND a matching joboffer)? Or am I going nuts? :)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I modified my answer based on your comment. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply, but am I not right in thinking that when you use an INNERJOIN you need to INNERJOIN 2 tables within the FROM clause based on certain columns which you can then use together (eg SELECT a.member_id, a.name FROM a INNER JOIN b USING (member_id, name))? Rather than just innerjoining 2 queries like you have done? I tried the query anyway but it errors, both individual queries work fine but not together like this. Am I missing something :)?