# How to write a sql to get the record in this dynamic table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table to store the dynamic attribute

The structure is like this:

```
id    itemid  value
----  ------  ------
1     1       A
2     2       B
3     3       C
4     1       B
5     2       C
```

So when I pass the multi-valued parameter

- Pass value `A B` result itemid `1`
- Pass value `B` result itemid `1 2`
- Pass value `B C` result `2`

How can I write this sql?
By the way i use mysql

Comment: Can you make the question clearer please? Also include what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Teifi sorry i use ipad to post this topic，its hard to edit， i just want to how to write the sql ， i really dont know how to select in this table

Comment: -1 for using an iPad.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk that's not really fair; I answer on my iPad and it is extremely frustrating. Even comments are a pain in the ass.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I would still try to type it out even if it was on my 4 inch Android screen.

Comment: Regardless of the method used to post the question, it should still be clear enough to read. I still don't understand the question.

Comment: @chanjianyi What do you mean 'pass'? I've never heard that in the context of SQL before so I'm not sure what you mean. Please edit your question to make it clearer!

Comment: Removed the gratuitous and large image (remember that imgur is blocked for some users) and replaced it with equivalent text. Sorry @ChrisLively.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk well I guess you're better than most of us. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'm in the lowest cast system there could be.

Comment: @Teifi pass means the condition... Like the answer 1 , plz see

Comment: More to the point, if you "pass" in `B C`, shouldn't the result be 2?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes you are right。i fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `(itemid, value)` has a `UNIQUE` constraint:

```
SELECT itemid
FROM tableX
WHERE value IN ('A', 'B')       -- the list
GROUP BY itemid
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 ;           -- the size of the list
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the behaviour you are looking for using a [SQL INTERSECT](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/intersect.php) query. Here is a brief example.

SELECT itemid FROM mytable WHERE value = 'A'
INTERSECT
SELECT itemid FROM mytable WHERE value = 'B'

Comment: Thx but I search this function in google ，it seems only for oracle? I use mysql

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621382/intersect-in-mysql