# MySql Union only return values from BOTH

Tags: mysql, union

```
Results 1
   Zac
   Dave
   Ned

Results 2
   Eric
   Mark
   Zac
```

This is the output from a select query.

```
select names from table where id=1 UNION select names from tables where id=2;
```

I want to select all from these results that are contained in both results. Union returns all the names (Zac only once). How do I get the query to only return Zac?

Comment: You're looking for an *intersection*, not a union. See this question: [Intersect in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621382/intersect-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
SELECT name FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
USING (name)
```

**Result**

```
| NAME |
--------
|  Zac |
```

[See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/815f3/1)

Comment: MySQL does not have an INTERSECT operator, unfortunately.

Comment: @DanJ Whoops; updated.

Answer (score 0):

Just use an `INNER JOIN` between the two tables.

```
SELECT a.name
FROM table1 AS a
JOIN table2 AS b ON a.name = b.name
```