# Multiple ID check in MYSQL WHERE condition

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have a query, I need to get a row only if all the ID match in WHERE clause

Here is the query

```
SELECT CompanyId
FROM vendors
WHERE VendorId
IN (
'306145244', '1011073437'
)
```

I want all the `CompanyId` which has both `vendorId` '306145244' and '1011073437'

If one of the `VendorId` match, I don't want that `companyId`. Both VendorId should be matched

While grouping I need 2 rows like below

```
company Id   Vendor Id
1             306145244
1             1011073437
2             306145244
2             306145244
```

If possible I want this query in `ORACLE`.

Comment: VendorId = '306145244' and VendorId = '1011073437'? Table structure please!

Comment: I assume there are 2 rows with the same companyID and different vendorID?

Comment: is VendorId is multivalued(comma-separated value)?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  CompanyId
FROM    vendors
WHERE   VendorId IN ('306145244', '1011073437')
GROUP   BY CompanyId
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34634/4)

OTHER LINK:

- [SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

---

if `vendorID` is not unique for every `CompanyId`, a `DISTINCT` keyword is need to count only unique values,

```
SELECT  CompanyId
FROM    vendors
WHERE   VendorId IN ('306145244', '1011073437')
GROUP   BY CompanyId
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT VendorId) = 2
```

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check it. Your query will give only one row for vendors. I need 2 rows for ('306145244', '1011073437')

Answer (score 0):

You might need to take a look at ALL.

```
SELECT CompanyId
FROM vendors
WHERE VendorId = ALL (
    query to get numbers.
)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/all-subqueries.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `CompanyId` , count( `CompanyId` )
FROM `vendors`
WHERE VendorId
IN (
'306145244', '1011073437'
)
GROUP BY `CompanyId`
HAVING count( `CompanyId` ) = 2;
```

Use this, this is working for me and tested.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check it. Your query will give only one row for vendors. I need 2 rows for ('306145244', '1011073437')

Comment: In this case I will get only one record for company, I need 2 record see the question

Answer (score 0):

In `SQL Server` what we can do is:

```
SELECT CompanyId
FROM vendors
WHERE VendorId
IN ('306145244')
intersect
SELECT CompanyId
FROM vendors
WHERE VendorId
IN ('1011073437')
```

But `MYSQL` doesn't support `intersect`. Hence we have to approach **[alternative to intersect in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621382/alternative-to-intersect-in-mysql)**

```
select distinct CompanyId
FROM vendors
where vendorId IN ('306145244')
and CompanyId IN
(SELECT CompanyId
FROM vendors
WHERE VendorId
IN ('1011073437'))
```

**Edit**

```
select  CompanyId,VendorId
FROM vendors
where vendorId IN ('306145244')
and CompanyId IN
(SELECT CompanyId
FROM vendors
WHERE VendorId
IN ('1011073437'))
union
select  CompanyId,VendorId
FROM vendors
where vendorId IN ('1011073437')
and CompanyId IN
(SELECT CompanyId
FROM vendors
WHERE VendorId
IN ('306145244'))
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83033/5)**

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check it. Your query will give only one row for vendors. I need 2 rows for ('306145244', '1011073437')

Comment: @Sahal Answer Edited. **:)**. It will worked in **Oracle** too

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT CompanyId,VendorId
FROM vendors
WHERE VendorId
IN (
select VendorId from vendors
)
order by CompanyId asc;
```

Hope it will help you.