# Retrieving rows that have multiple association entries

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have an ASOC-type table with the following entries:

```
+----------+----------+
| PERSON   | SKILL    |
+----------+----------+
| Bob      | Java     |
| Bob      | Database |
| Sarah    | Java     |
| Sarah    | HTML     |
| Jane     | Java     |
| Jane     | HTML     |
| Jane     | Database |
+----------+----------+
```

I want a query that will return the list of persons who have both the Java and Database skills, i.e. Bob and Jane.

If I run a query like:

```
SELECT PERSON
FROM   PERSON_SKILLS_ASOC
WHERE  SKILL = 'Java'
OR     SKILL = 'Database'
```

I will get Sarah as well, who doesn't qualify for the position I'm trying to fill. Do I need to do some kind of union/intersection query?

I'm on MySQL. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change `OR` to `AND` as you want a person that posses both skills and not one or another.

Comment: WHERE skill in ('java','database') GROUP BY person HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 -- where '2' is the number of items in the IN() argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.person
from (select person from person_skills_asoc where skill = 'Java') a
     (select person from person_skills_asoc where skill = 'Database') b
where a.person = b.person;
```

or

```
select a.person
from person_skills_asoc a, person_skills_asoc b
where a.person = b.person
  and a.skill = 'Java'
  and b.skill = 'Database';
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not worked in MySQL for years, so my syntax may be off slightly, but the gist is `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT
    PSA1.Person
FROM
    PERSON_SKILLS_ASOC AS PSA1
WHERE
        PSA1.Skill = 'Java'
    AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PERSON_SKILLS_ASOC AS PSA2 WHERE PSA1.Person = PSA2.Person AND PSA2.Skill = 'Database')
```

You can also achieve this with a join.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server for example you could use `INTERSECT`, apparently that's not available in MySQL (yet?). A possible solution using a self join (check the **[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45d94/3)**):

```
SELECT P1.PERSON
FROM   PERSON_SKILLS_ASOC AS P1
INNER JOIN PERSON_SKILLS_ASOC AS P2 ON P1.PERSON = P2.PERSON
WHERE  P1.SKILL = 'Java'
       AND P2.SKILL = 'Database';
```

There is also another nice answer on SO on alternatives for `INTERSECT` in MySQL here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3201426/249353.

Answer (score 0):

Using joins like this:-

```
SELECT a.PERSON
FROM   PERSON_SKILLS_ASOC a
INNER JOIN PERSON_SKILLS_ASOC b ON a.PERSON = b.PERSON
WHERE  a.SKILL = 'Java'
AND    b.SKILL = 'Database'
```

Or using counts:-

```
SELECT PERSON
FROM   PERSON_SKILLS_ASOC a
WHERE  SKILL IN ('Java', 'Database')
GROUP BY PERSON
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT SKILL) = 2
```