# Select columns from table where value of columns not equal 'myvalue'

Tags: mysql, multiple-columns

I have a very critical code. I'm trying to select all records from two columns of one table that matches the records of another table in one column.
here's a my result so far

```
SELECT username FROM users 
WHERE username NOT IN (SELECT friend FROM friends WHERE friend = 'user1') 
AND username NOT IN (SELECT you FROM friends WHERE you = 'user1')
```

[live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f134/94)

This can't be right...
I want the records in column [username] that doesn't match 'user1' in both columns [you] and [friend] in table {friends} to be a result of that sql selection.
please see the demo for more understanding.
thanks for your help.

Problem solved, hopefully this can help other people

```
SELECT username,you,friend FROM users, friends 
WHERE you IN (SELECT you FROM friends WHERE you != 'user1') 
AND friend IN (SELECT friend FROM friends WHERE friend != 'user1')
AND username IN (you,friend)
```

and this is a [Live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f134/94)

Comment: Why can't you use a regular join and <> to check the fields aren't equal to both values?  Or what rows do you want returned in your fiddle?

Comment: if you could please, edit my code in the demo...

Comment: Because I'm trying to elicit what you WANT to happen.  With data.  Which rows of the three in the sample do you want the query to return?

Comment: Can you provide test data and result you want to achieve?

Comment: the username row... :)

Comment: Do you want to get `user3`, `user4` and `user5`?

Comment: all the usernames from table users that doesn't mactch 'user1' in table friends in columns 'you' and 'friend'

Comment: So just the third row in your SQL fiddle?

Comment: yes, every 'you' who's not a friend with 'user1' and every 'friend' who's 'you' is not 'user1' that match the usernames in table users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are now down to two ways what you want can be interpreted.

**Option1** - this is exactly what I think you asked for, but not what I think you want.

```
SELECT username FROM users u, friends f
WHERE username = f.friend and f.friend <> 'user1'
union
SELECT username FROM users u, friends f
WHERE username = f.you and f.you <> 'user1'
```

**Option2** - this is what I think you want.  See [how to translate it to mysql.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621382/alternative-to-intersect-in-mysql/3201426#3201426)
    SELECT username FROM users u, friends f
    WHERE username = f.friend and f.friend <> 'user1'
    intersect
    SELECT username FROM users u, friends f
    WHERE username = f.you and f.you <> 'user1'

Comment: The second option doesn't work
the first option works pretty much like mine
I wanted both columns records of table friends that doesn't equal 'user1' to return and match usernames in tables users and then return those usernames

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f134/53 these results might give u a picture of what I want.

Comment: SELECT you,friend FROM friends 
WHERE you <> 'user1' and friend <> 'user1'
returns that and is very simple.