# How do I output the mutual results appearing in two queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I have made 2 simple queries which output the forename and surname of people based upon the value of a column "role" in a junction table they are associated with.

Lets say that the output is:

```
Kevin Baker
Julie Willis
Gregory Hilliard
Joe Swanson
Patrick Day
Bethany Row
```

for one of the query outputs and:

```
Kevin Baker
Michael Winter
Ellie Patterson
```

for the other.

I want to be able to make a query which outputs the values that appear in both of these tables i.e. I want it to output Kevin Baker in this case.

Is there a simple way to do this based upon the two queries I have already made?

Comment: Use UNION statement between one query and other.

Comment: Is the syntax for this:

QUERY1
UNION
QUERY2
? Does it need any brackets etc...?
I tried it this way but the output was incorrect. I thought UNION was similar to saying "or" so instead of finding the mutual results, it finds the results in QUERY1 or QUERY2. Am I wrong?

Comment: No it doesn't need any brakets. If you post your query it will be easier to provide you an appropriated answer. In order to do a UNION you have to have the same number of columns on the to sql commands and all types needs to be the same.

Comment: Also UNION by default makes a DISTINCT over the two queries, to do it without the distinc you have ot use UNION ALL

Comment: I need something similar to INTERSECT which is not included in MySQL syntax. I will refer to this thread for further research http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621382/alternative-to-intersect-in-mysql

Comment: Post your query and the desired result based on the data you show.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to do it myself. I am not sure if it is the best method but it was simple and works.

I kept the first query the same and added

```
AND IN()
```

to the end of the WHERE statement.

I then pasted the second query into the IN statement and altered it to only SELECT the id of the related attributes in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an intersect just JOIN these queries:

```
Select Q1.Name FROM (QUERY1) Q1
JOIN 
(QUERY2) Q2 On Query1.Name=Q2.Name
```

Comment: How do I name the queries in order to do this? At the moment, the two queries are two SELECT-FROM-WHERE blocks.

Comment: Just replace `Query1` and `Query2` with your queries.

Comment: or right, are you actually assigning the names Q1 and Q2 to the queries at that point? Could you also use (QUERY1) AS Q1 like you do when abbreviating tables?