# In MySQL, How can I apply the Intersection usage to more than 3 select sentences?

Tags: mysql

I have 9 select sentences. I want to get the intersection of the 9 select results. 
But I applied intersect to my codes, but it didn't work.

Below is my code.

```
 (SELECT code_co.code, code_co.disease_co, code_en.disease_en
 FROM code_co
 LEFT JOIN code_en ON code_en.code = code_co.code
 LEFT JOIN note ON note.code = code_co.code
 LEFT JOIN inclusion ON inclusion.code = code_co.code
 LEFT JOIN exclusion ON exclusion.code = code_co.code
 LEFT JOIN ds ON code_co.code = ds.code
 LEFT JOIN tx ON code_co.code = tx.code
 LEFT JOIN sx ON code_co.code = sx.code
 CROSS JOIN (
     SELECT CONCAT(  '%', ds_word.ds_en,  '%' ) AS pattern
     FROM ds_word
     WHERE ds_co LIKE  '%".$search[0]."%'
     LIMIT 0 , 1
     )const
 WHERE note LIKE const.pattern
 OR ds_content LIKE const.pattern
 OR disease_en LIKE const.pattern 
 OR sx_content LIKE const.pattern
 OR tx_content LIKE const.pattern
 OR exclusion LIKE const.pattern
 OR inclusion LIKE const.pattern
 )
 intersect

 (SELECT code_co.code, code_co.disease_co, code_en.disease_en
 FROM code_co
 LEFT JOIN code_en ON code_en.code = code_co.code
 LEFT JOIN note ON note.code = code_co.code
 LEFT JOIN inclusion ON inclusion.code = code_co.code
 LEFT JOIN exclusion ON exclusion.code = code_co.code
 LEFT JOIN ds ON code_co.code = ds.code
 LEFT JOIN tx ON code_co.code = tx.code
 LEFT JOIN sx ON code_co.code = sx.code
 CROSS JOIN (
 SELECT CONCAT(  '%', ds_word.ds_en,  '%' ) AS pattern
      FROM ds_word
      WHERE ds_co LIKE  '%".$search[1]."%'
      ....
 OR inclusion LIKE const.pattern
 )

intersect

(SELECT code_co.code, code_co.disease_co, code_en.disease_en
 FROM code_co
 LEFT JOIN code_en ON code_en.code = code_co.code
 ... /* for search[2] */
 OR inclusion LIKE const.pattern
 )
```

But intersect is not working. 
Please help me for intersect usage.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't have an intersect instruction, you may check how to emulate here:

[Alternative to Intersect in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621382/alternative-to-intersect-in-mysql)

I suposse you are using MySQL cause of the question tag