# Intersection of two MySql queries

Tags: mysql, intersection

I have a table where each data has a date when it was inserted in form of two columns, year and week:

```
+------+------+-------+
| Week | Year | Value |
+------+------+-------+
| 1    | 2014 | 5     |
| 5    | 2014 | 23    |
| 6    | 2014 | 12    |
| 7    | 2014 | 43    |
| 8    | 2014 | 4     |
| 9    | 2014 | 2     |
| 26   | 2013 | 21    |
| 27   | 2013 | 17    |
| 28   | 2013 | 42    |
| 31   | 2013 | 5     |
| ...  | ...  | ..    |
+------+------+-------+
```

I need a query to get data that was inserted between two dates (year, week). I guess that it should be alternative to intersection of two queries, one with a starting date and the second with ending data, but I can't get it to work. Any help or sugestion?

Here is my shot but INTERSECT is not supported in MySql:

```
(SELECT SUM(Duration), Week, Type, Year 
 FROM UP26rotordowntime 
 WHERE (Year>=2013) 
 AND (Week >=01) 
 GROUP BY Week)

INTERSECT

(SELECT SUM(Duration), Week, Type, Year 
 FROM UP26rotordowntime 
 WHERE (Year<=2014) 
 AND (Week <=14) 
 GROUP BY Week)
```

Comment: This is tagged MySQL ?!?!

Comment: Not sure I got you. What's wrong with `WHERE Year BETWEEN 2013 AND 2014` ?

Comment: @AlmaDo It will not give good results since Year and Week need to be "connected" somehow.

Comment: What about UNION instead INTERSECT?

Comment: @bksi in that case with second query I would include results that are discarded in the first one.

Comment: did you saw this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621382/alternative-to-intersect-in-mysql

Comment: It is always good to have some primary key that you can use with IN clause. In that case your query will be very easy to construct

Comment: I have that as ID column but trying to figure out how to construct all of these info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put simple logic in WHERE conditions and use (year,week) pairs for GROUP BY:

```
SELECT SUM(Duration), Week, Type, Year 
FROM UP26rotordowntime 
WHERE Year = 2005 AND Week >= 10
   OR Year BETWEEN 2006 AND 2013
   OR Year = 2014 AND Week <= 14
GROUP BY Year,Week
```

Comment: It's close.. but in this case I'm getting some weeks that I dont have in table??!? Which is totally confusing. And Week 7,8 and 9 are not included.

Comment: Its just an example for more than two years, in your case just skip middle condition and put exact values you need.

Comment: I realize that, but still this is including all data since you are using `OR`  so that data which is discarded with `WHERE Year = 2005 AND Week >= 10` will be included with `Year = 2014 AND Week <= 14`

Comment: Note equality sign on year. Basically you split data into three parts: some weeks in the first year (and first year only), then all data from years in the middle, then some weeks from the last year (and last year only).

Answer (score 0):

If you have id the query is very simple:

```
SELECT SUM(Duration), Week, Type, Year FROM UP26rotordowntime 
WHERE ID IN (
  SELECT ID FROM UP26rotordowntime WHERE (Year>=2013) AND (Week >=01) )
OR ID IN (
  SELECT ID FROM UP26rotordowntime WHERE (Year<=2014) AND (Week <=14))
GROUP BY Week
```

This should return you the intersect you need

Comment: With this query I'm getting only data from 2014, none from 2013 is included :/

Comment: I think that the only solution should be INNER JOIN but I don't know how to construct it since it should join queries from same table

Comment: Sorry my mistake, you should use OR instead AND. See my edited answer