# intersect to inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

please how to convert this query with inner join ?

```
(SELECT DISTINCT tables.table_id AS 'Available table ID'
   FROM tables, reservation 
  WHERE tables.table_id = reservation.table_id 
    AND ((start_time <> ? AND date = ?)
          OR (date <> ?)) 
          OR status = 1)
INTERSECT
(SELECT DISTINCT tables.table_id AS 'Available table ID'
   FROM tables, reservation 
  WHERE tables.table_id = reservation.table_id 
    AND ((start_time <> ? AND date = ?) 
          OR (date <> ? AND reservation.table_id <> ?))
          OR status=1)
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java. I've edited the question to remove the `Java` tag, but just a heads-up.

Comment: Hopefully the query is a little more readable now

Comment: @Strawberry The question is tagged MySQL, which has no `INTERSECT` keyword.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative to Intersect in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621382/alternative-to-intersect-in-mysql)

Answer (score -1):

You could try this: (I am not sure if you are looking for this answer)

```
(SELECT DISTINCT tables.table_id AS 'Available table ID'
   FROM tables JOIN reservation 
   ON (tables.table_id = reservation.table_id) 
   WHERE start_time <> ? AND date = ?
         OR (date <> ?)) 
         OR status = 1
INTERSECT
(SELECT DISTINCT tables.table_id AS 'Available table ID'
   FROM tables JOIN reservation 
   ON (tables.table_id = reservation.table_id) 
   WHERE start_time <> ? AND date = ? 
        OR date <> ? AND reservation.table_id <> ?)
        OR status=1
```