# mysql select two columns by pair of values

Tags: mysql, intersect

I need to get all products from product_attributes table where 
I have several pairs of attribute id and filter text value.

It is made harder because text is stored as array separated by `;`.

```
       TABLE product_attribute

        Fields product_id, attribute_id, text

        SELECT  pa.product_id  FROM  product_attribute as pa  

WHERE   (
 (pa.attribute_id = '15' AND pa.text LIKE '%Male%' ) 
  AND 
(pa.attribute_id = '12'  AND  pa.text  LIKE  '%Cream%'  )
 )
```

Obviously this does not work, because attribute_id cant be 12 and 15 same time.

And I cannot use OR here because it will 
return all products (all male) + (all cream)

and I need only intersection (male cream)

Got answer here. 
[Alternative to Intersect in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621382/alternative-to-intersect-in-mysql)

My variant:

```
SELECT  paz.product_id 
FROM  (
( SELECT product_id FROM oc_product_attribute WHERE attribute_id = '15' AND text LIKE '%male%' )   
UNION ALL
( SELECT product_id FROM oc_product_attribute WHERE attribute_id = '12'  AND text  LIKE  '%creme%' )  
)  paz GROUP BY paz.product_id  HAVING COUNT(*)=2
```

And Gordon Linoff variant^

```
SELECT pa.product_id 
FROM product_attribute pa 
GROUP BY pa.product_id
HAVING SUM(pa.attribute_id = '15' AND pa.text LIKE '%Male%') > 0 AND
       SUM(pa.attribute_id = '12' AND pa.text LIKE '%Cream%');
```

Comment: And I cannot use OR here because it will return all products with and I need only intersection,

Comment: try to make union...

Answer (score 1):

I often approach these using `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT pa.product_id 
FROM product_attribute pa 
GROUP BY pa.product_id
HAVING SUM(pa.attribute_id = '15' AND pa.text LIKE '%Male%') > 0 AND
       SUM(pa.attribute_id = '12' AND pa.text LIKE '%Cream%') > 0;
```

Each condition in the `HAVING` clause verifies that there is at least one row meeting the particular condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 2 attributes to compare then use a self join to `product_attribute`

```
SELECT 
  pa.product_id 
FROM
  product_attribute AS pa 
  JOIN product_attribute AS pa1 USING (product_id) 
WHERE pa.attribute_id = '15' 
  AND pa.text LIKE '%Male%' 
  AND pa1.attribute_id = '12' 
  AND pa1.text LIKE '%Cream%'
```

Another way would be using `COUNT/GROUP BY /HAVING`

```
SELECT 
  pa.product_id 
FROM
  product_attribute AS pa 
WHERE pa.attribute_id IN ('15', '12') 
  AND (
    pa.text LIKE '%Male%' 
    OR pa.text LIKE '%Cream%'
  ) 
GROUP BY pa.product_id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pa.attribute_id) = 2
```

Comment: Thought about it but theese are dynamic.

Comment: Second: And what if there are same text fields in attributes 15 and 12, like "yes" or "no", It can return wrong result.

Comment: @Firestarter1 see another query hope you will get the idea to make dynamic conditions for your dynamic attributes for attribute_ids put them in `in()` clasue for text add `ORs` in like part and in the `HAVING` part put the count of attributes you want to compare `3,4,5...`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  pa.product_id  FROM  product_attribute as pa  
WHERE   
(pa.attribute_id = '15' AND pa.text LIKE '%Male%' ) 
union
SELECT  pa.product_id  FROM  product_attribute as pa  
WHERE   
(pa.attribute_id = '12' AND pa.text LIKE '%Male%' )
```

combine with union...

you also can do everything together and distinct the results

```
select a.* from 
(select * from product_attribute where pa.attribute_id = '15' or 
pa.attribute_id = '12')  as a 
where  a.text LIKE '%Male%' or a.text = '%Cream%'
```

Comment: Wont  UNION behave same as OR here?

Comment: ummm... maybe i didnt understand you, the union will make the first select and then the second select and combine them together what exactly you want to happen?

Comment: There is correct SQL using UNION ALL and then using duplicates only http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621382/alternative-to-intersect-in-mysql

Comment: you also can do something like this select a.* from (select * from product_attribute where pa.attribute_id = '15' or pa.attribute_id = '12')  as a where  a.text LIKE '%Male%' or a.text = '%Cream%'