# how to write query for retrive common data

Tags: mysql, intersect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Intersect in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621382/intersect-in-mysql)

I have do a php project for retrieving common data.I am little weak in writing MySQL query.  i was tried different ways .But i cannot get proper output

My table is

```
 Id  Product-1   product-2
 -------------------------
 1      A           B
 2      B           C
 3      C           A
 4      E           B
 5      H           C
```

This is my table .I want to write a MySQL query retrieve common elements.
eg:
Here A,B be will comes to Product-1,Product-2,
I want to retrieve common element element of A,B
Here The output is C

```
    3      C           A
    2      B           C
```

both row can contain either A,B in  Product-1 or product-2

Same like A,c common element is B  .How to write Query for this... in sql we can use Intersect operation 
But MySQL i don't  have any idea .Please help me...

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621382/intersect-in-mysql , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300322/intersect-in-mysql

Comment: Please can you try and clarify your request, personally at least I can't really see what you are asking for so can't assist

Answer (score 2):

What I would recommend, instead of using the columns for two way relationships, which complicates the query, keep the relationships one way.

So, instead of the following meaning `A to C` and `C to A`:

```
Id  Product-1   Product-2
 -------------------------
 3      C           A
```

You actually do this to mean `A to C` and `C to A`:

```
Id  Product-1   Product-2
 -------------------------
 2      A           C
 3      C           A
```

Then, assuming no duplicates, your query is simply this:

```
SELECT Product-1
FROM tablename
WHERE Product-2 IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY Product-1
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

However, with your data, the following query will give the common elements for `'A', 'B'`:

```
SELECT Product-1 FROM
((SELECT Product-1, Product-2
 FROM tablename)
UNION
(SELECT Product-2, Product-1
 FROM tablename)) t
WHERE Product-2 IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY Product-1
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

What I've done is create a derived table that has a copy of the relationships reversed, so that I get the relationships to be one way, and then proceed normally.