# mysql intersect

Tags: mysql

I'm new to mysql so please be kind. I'm getting the following error for my script and im not sure whats wrong with it.

```
SELECT uoid 
FROM mint 
WHERE mint_id='6' and userid='3836'
INTERSECT 
SELECT id as uoid
FROM cats 
WHERE category='Health, Fitness' 
ORDER BY 1;
```

gives

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTERSECT SELECT id as uoid FROM cats WHERE category='Health, Fitness'' at line 4
```

Comment: That is because MySql does not have a INTERSECT keyword. Possibly interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621382/intersect-in-mysql.

Comment: ...and this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2300322/306084

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL does not have an INTERSECT keyword. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2300322/306084) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2621382/306084) for suggestions about how to achieve what you're after.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it to you since the links you gave helped fix my problem

Answer (score 1):

`INTERSECT` is not supported in MySQL. You need to restructure your query somehow. You might be able to use a subquery if you version of MySQL supports subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

This is because intersect only work on same table, not on different tables as you are trying.
See [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-intersect-clause.htm)

In place of intersect use join statement syntax.
And INTERSECT does exist in sql

Answer (score 0):

The [`INTERSECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/intersect.html) operator has become available for MySQL since [version 8.0.31](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-31.html), released in 10 November 2022. You can now do the following:

```
SELECT uoid FROM mint WHERE mint_id='6' and userid='3836'
INTERSECT 
SELECT id as uoid FROM cats WHERE category='Health, Fitness' 
ORDER BY 1;
```