# Rails SQL INTERSECT not working

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I want to get the mutual friends of a user, i.e people that I follow and that follow me back:

```
# get users I'm following
following_ids = "SELECT followed_id FROM relationships WHERE follower_id = #{self.id}"

# get user that are following me
follower_ids = "SELECT follower_id FROM relationships WHERE followed_id = #{self.id}"

User.where("id IN (#{following_ids} INTERSECT #{follower_ids})")
```

However, I get the following error:

> Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'INTERSECT SELECT follower_id FROM relationships WHERE
>   followed_id = 2))' at line 1: SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (id
>   IN (SELECT followed_id FROM relationships WHERE follower_id = 2
>   INTERSECT SELECT follower_id FROM relationships WHERE followed_id =
>   2))

The individual queries do work, so I know it's a problem with the INTERSECT keyword.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't have `INTERSECT`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433587/mysql-intersect), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300322/intersect-in-mysql) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621382/alternative-to-intersect-in-mysql) for more information.