# Work around for intersect keyword in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have requirement of getting intersection of some results in mysql DB. But after googling came to know that there is no [mysql intersect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433587/mysql-intersect) keyword available . Following are my sample tables.

```
gene table
+------+--------+---------+
| id   | symbol | test_id |
+------+--------+---------+
|   -1 | A      |      -1 |
|    8 | A      |       3 |
|    9 | G      |       3 |
|   -1 | A      |      -1 |
|   -2 | B      |      -1 |
|   -3 | C      |      -1 |
|    1 | A      |       1 |
|    2 | B      |       1 |
|    3 | C      |       1 |
|    4 | B      |       2 |
|    5 | C      |       2 |
|    6 | D      |       2 |
|    7 | E      |       2 |
|    8 | A      |       3 |
|    9 | G      |       3 |
|   10 | F      |       3 |
|   11 | C      |       3 |
|   12 | C      |       4 |
|   13 | G      |       4 |
|   14 | F      |       4 |
|   15 | M      |       4 |
|   16 | N      |       4 |
+------+--------+---------+

test table
+------+-------+
| id   | name  |
+------+-------+
|   -1 | test0 |
|    3 | test3 |
|   -1 | test0 |
|    1 | test1 |
|    2 | test2 |
|    3 | test3 |
|    4 | test4 |
+------+-------+
```

Now I want to formulate a query which will give me the tests which are common for provided genes. e.g. I will provide gene A, B, C and I should get the following result:

```
 id    name   id    symbol 
---------------------------    
 -1 | test0 |   -1 | A
 -1 | test0 |   -2 | B
 -1 | test0 |   -3 | C
  1 | test1 |    1 | A
  1 | test1 |    2 | B
  1 | test1 |    3 | C
```

I just tried to form a query by following way but didn't work, getting empty resultset and if I use 'or' in where clause getting tests for all genes in where clause.

```
select distinct t.id, t.name, g.id, g.symbol from tests t 
join genes g on t.id = g.test_id 
where g.symbol = 'A' and g.symbol='B' and g.symbol='C';
```

Please help me to construct the query.

Comment: `where g.symbol in ('A','B','C')`

Comment: @splash58 I tried 'or' instead of 'and' I got tests of all the three genes however I need only intersection(common to these three genes)

Comment: Why would you not want test with id -1 returned? This also has genes A, B and C?

Comment: Edited the result table to reflect the change that you suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to filter the records with your criteria, then group by `test.id` to check that it matches **all** the criteria:

```
SELECT  t.id
FROM    tests AS t
        INNER JOIN genes AS g
            ON t.id = g.test_id 
WHERE   g.symbol in ('A','B','C')
GROUP BY t.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT g.symbol) = 3;
```

So the key line is here:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT g.symbol) = 3;
```

If, like test 2, there is only a match on 'B', then the count will return 1 and the test will be excluded. The number of items you are checking for must match the number in the HAVING clause.

If you then need to get the full data out, you just need to join back to your table:

```
SELECT  t.id, t.name, g.id, g.symbol
FROM    genes AS g
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  t.id, t.name
            FROM    tests AS t
                    INNER JOIN genes AS g
                        ON t.id = g.test_id 
            WHERE   g.symbol in ('A','B','C')
            GROUP BY t.id, t.name
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT g.symbol) = 3
        ) t
            ON t.id = g.test_id;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db764/4)**

Comment: I'll test it and get back to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change those `AND` conditions to `OR` condition like below cause at any point in time `g.symbol` can hold only one value and not multiple value. that's why you are getting empty result set.

```
select t.id, t.name, g.id, g.symbol from tests t 
join genes g on t.id = g.test_id 
where (g.symbol = 'A' or g.symbol='B' or g.symbol='C')
and g.test_id = 1;
```

(OR) use a `IN` operator like

```
select t.id, t.name, g.id, g.symbol from tests t 
join genes g on t.id = g.test_id 
where g.symbol in ('A','B','C')
and g.test_id = 1;
```

Comment: I tried this as well. I have mentioned it in my question itself. This didn't work. Thanks for reply.

Comment: And yes you are getting absolute correct result. Try analyzing it yourself and you will find it out.

Comment: I'll provide you query results 1 min.

Comment: @AshokDongare, see edit in answer if it help. If you want to get only test_id = 1 then add that condition to your `where` clause.

Comment: No no... not only test with test_id=1. it could be any tests. I just provided that as a sample

Comment: First you clarify yourself the end result you are trying to obtain and then edit your post accordingly.