# Querying an entry with multiple categories?

Tags: mysql, sql, tags

I want to have a picture gallery and each gallery will be marked with a set of tags, I want users to be able to search for any number of these tags and I'd like if it were somewhat efficient. I don't really know where to begin.

Each category has an entry in the 'categories' table, something like this:

```
id | name | description
---+------+------------------------------------
0  | cats | This is a gallery full of cats
1  | dogs | This is a gallery full of dogs
```

and each entry in the 'galleries' table would have multiple category IDs stored for each category they belong in (though I'm not sure how I'd store them or query them at this time)

If it weren't for the search function I planned on I'd just serialize the category array, but that's not efficient to query at all.

Comment: I think you'll need a third table...

Comment: Hm, yeah I think I know what you mean now that you mention it. The third table would have (Gallery ID | Category ID) and I'd just insert the gallery ID multiple times with different categories. (0 | 0, 0 | 1) and so on.

Comment: Yep. That's it. See? You figured it out on your own!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go for third normal form

```
 gallery 
 id | desc
----+---------
1   | dogs
2   | cats
3   | cats and dogs playing
```

.

```
gallery_category
gallery_id | category_id 
-----------+-------------
 1         | 1
 2         | 0
 3         | 0
 3         | 1
```

then use <strike>union</strike> intersect

```
 select gallery_id from gallery_category where category_id=1
 INTERSECT 
 select gallery_id from gallery_category where category_id=0
```

with indices on both columns of gallery_category this should be reasonably fast.

unfortunately mysql doesn't do intersect, but you can get the same effect with join.

```
select a.gallery_id 
  from  gallery_category as a 
  join  gallery_category as b on a.gallery_id = b.gallery_id
  where a.category_id=1 and b.category_id=0
```

Comment: the union doesn't make sense, it would be better to just use IN: `SELECT gallery_id FROM gallery_category WHERE category_ID IN (0,1);` that would return the exact same results as your union

Comment: Thanks, you've both been a great help

Comment: You're right, I thought "intersect". and Wrote "union",
http://stackoverflow.com/q/2300322/340140