# SQL Intersect with Eloquent on Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have just look the laravel documentation, and I don't see any intersect method with Eloquent... How can I do this ?

```
SELECT * FROM `store_1`
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM `store_2`
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM `store_3`
```

Comment: You tagged this `MySQL`, AFAIK, that has no `INTERSECT`, or did I miss it's introduction? Anyway: [look at this for `INTERSECT` in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300322/intersect-in-mysql), and you can probably rewrite it to that method.

Comment: You have option to use `DB::raw(...)`.

Comment: There is no intersect in `Query\Builder` so you need `DB::raw` and if it's `MySql`, then it might be `from(DB::raw('main_table join another_table using (fields) join ...'))->distinct()` since there's no `intersect`.