# SQL query Impossibile WHERE with two condition

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to execute this query:

```
SELECT * FROM person JOIN colors ON person.IDA=colors.IDA where Age=20 AND (Color="Black" AND Color="Orange")
```

So I need a joined table with all the rows that have

- person.Age = 20
- colors.Color = Black
- colors.Color = Orange

I can query correctly only with one condition

```
SELECT * from person join colors on person.IDA = colors.IDA WHERE Age=20 and colors.Color="Black"
```

(result)

```
+-----+------+-----+------+------+-------+
| IDA | Name | Age | ID   | IDA  | Color |
+-----+------+-----+------+------+-------+
|   1 | John |  20 |    4 |    1 | Black |
|   3 | Bob  |  20 |   13 |    3 | Black |
|   3 | Bob  |  20 |   16 |    3 | Black |
+-----+------+-----+------+------+-------+
```

So I'm expecting a result like that when (Color="Black" AND Color="Orange"):

```
+-----+------+-----+------+------+--------+
| IDA | Name | Age | ID   | IDA  | Color  |
+-----+------+-----+------+------+--------+
|   1 | John |  20 |    3 |    1 | Orange |
|   1 | John |  20 |    4 |    1 | Black  |
|   3 | Bob  |  20 |   11 |    3 | Orange |
|   3 | Bob  |  20 |   13 |    3 | Black  |
+-----+------+-----+------+------+--------+
```

But I get Impossible WHERE when EXPLAIN the query.

DUMP:

**person:**

```
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| IDA   | int(50)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Name  | tinytext | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Age   | int(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

+-----+------+-----+
| IDA | Name | Age |
+-----+------+-----+
|   1 | John |  20 |
|   2 | Alex |  21 |
|   3 | Bob  |  20 |
+-----+------+-----+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**color**

```
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID    | int(50)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| IDA   | int(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Color | tinytext | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

+----+-----+--------+
| ID | IDA | Color  |
+----+-----+--------+
|  1 |   1 | White  |
|  2 |   1 | White  |
|  3 |   1 | Orange |
|  4 |   1 | Black  |
|  5 |   2 | Black  |
|  6 |   2 | Black  |
|  7 |   2 | Black  |
|  8 |   2 | Black  |
|  9 |   2 | Orange |
| 10 |   2 | Yellow |
| 11 |   3 | Orange |
| 12 |   3 | White  |
| 13 |   3 | Black  |
| 14 |   3 | Yellow |
| 15 |   1 | Orange |
| 16 |   3 | Black  |
+----+-----+--------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**EDIT:**

Thank you for the answers, I think I've picked the wrong query: I'm looking for a result that have BOTH Black and Orange. If I substitute Black with White:

```
SELECT * FROM person JOIN colors ON person.IDA=colors.IDA where Color="White" OR  Color="Orange"
```

I will get

```
|   2 | Alex |  21 |  9 |   2 | Orange |
```

Alex have only the color Orange, not Orange and White

```
+-----+------+-----+----+-----+--------+
| IDA | Name | Age | ID | IDA | Color  |
+-----+------+-----+----+-----+--------+
|   1 | John |  20 |  1 |   1 | White  |
|   1 | John |  20 |  2 |   1 | White  |
|   1 | John |  20 |  3 |   1 | Orange |
|   2 | Alex |  21 |  9 |   2 | Orange |
|   3 | Bob  |  20 | 11 |   3 | Orange |
|   3 | Bob  |  20 | 12 |   3 | White  |
|   1 | John |  20 | 15 |   1 | Orange |
+-----+------+-----+----+-----+--------+
```

Comment: `(Color="Black" OR Color="Orange")`...?

Comment: The suggested way of doing this in MySQL is usually to have an additional join for each condition, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300322/intersect-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "OR":

```
SELECT * FROM person
JOIN colors ON person.IDA=colors.IDA
where person.Age=20 AND (colors.Color="Black" OR colors.Color="Orange")
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you're looking for something such as this (i.e. basically an `OR` condition):

```
SELECT * from person join colors 
    on person.IDA = colors.IDA 
 WHERE Age=20 and (colors.Color="Black" or colors.Color="Orange")
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM person JOIN colors ON person.IDA=colors.IDA where Age=20 AND (Color="Black" AND Color="Orange").

You need to use (Color="Black" OR Color="Orange") instead of (Color="Black" AND Color="Orange")

Answer (score 0):

You need to change AND operator to OR.

```
WHERE Age=20 OR colors.Color="Black"
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for results from both Black and Orange.  If so, use the OR operator instead of AND.

Answer (score 0):

The WHERE is impossible because you are requiring Color to be both black and orange at the same time.

You can use `OR` instead of `AND` to search for either color.

```
SELECT * FROM person JOIN colors
  ON person.IDA=colors.IDA
  WHERE
    Age=20 AND
    (Color="Black" OR Color="Orange")
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM person
JOIN colors ON person.IDA=colors.IDA
WHERE Age=20
  AND `person`.`IDA` IN
    (SELECT *
     FROM person
     JOIN colors ON person.IDA=colors.IDA
     WHERE `color` = 'Black' INTERSECT
       SELECT *
       FROM person
       JOIN colors ON person.IDA=colors.IDA WHERE `color` = 'Orange');
```

You can use `intersect` operator in mysql which will find person who have both colors by taking the common person for both tables.