# Replace INTERSECT to work with phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

I'm fairly new to SQL and phpmyadmin, but in my query I have an error at intersect and I am wondering how to change that so it will print my table.

```
SELECT cust_code, cust_fname, cust_lname FROM lgcustomer join lginvoice         
USING (cust_code) WHERE employee_id = 83649

INTERSECT

SELECT cust_code, cust_fname, cust_lname FROM lgcustomer join lginvoice      
USING (cust_code) WHERE employee_id = 83677

ORDER BY cust_lname, cust_fname;
```

[image: What it is suppose to look like]

Comment: may be this one help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300322/intersect-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

`INTERSECT` operator is not available in MySQL. You can use `EXISTS` in this case:

```
SELECT c1.cust_code, c1.cust_fname, c1.cust_lname 
FROM lgcustomer as c1
JOIN lginvoice         
USING (cust_code) 
WHERE employee_id = 83649 AND 
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM lgcustomer as c2
              join lginvoice      
              USING (cust_code) 
              WHERE employee_id = 83677 and 
                    c1.cust_code = c2.cust_code and 
                    c1.cust_fname = c2.cust_fname and 
                    c1.cust_lname = c2.cust_lname)
```

Comment: When I use that code it prints out all the customers and not the customers between 83649 and 83677

Comment: @RyanB I can't see how this could be possible. Can you please post some sample data so that I can reproduce the issue?

Comment: I put an image in my question on what it is suppose to look like.

Comment: @xDD Using the data posted I cannot reproduce the issue. Also, it is always preferable to post sample data in textual format, as, this way, it is easier to consume this data in order build a mock-up.