# Find Values between two different columns in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

table one

```
+----------------------+
|column A | Column B|
|   2     |    4    | 
|   3     |    5    |
|   1     |    2    |
|   1     |    2    |
|   8     |    7    |
+----------------------+
```

Output

```
+-------+
|1 | 2  |
|1 | 2  |
+-------+
```

i want to print only the above output without COUNT, and any duplicate record example?  please help

Comment: Hello showrya. Could you explain please the logic behind the output? All results that have the value 1 in Column A for example?

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY, which is likely to prove problematic, either now or in the near future

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300322/intersect-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

how about below where cluase

```
   select * from t where columnA=1 and columnB=2
```

or

```
  select columnA,columnB from t
  group by columnA,columnB
  having count(*)>1
```

or you can use `exists`

```
select t1.* from t t1 where exists 
       (select 1 from t t2 where t2.columnA=t1.columnA
        and t2.columnB=t1.columnB group by columnA,columnB
        having count(*)>1
        )
```

Comment: is this possible without COUNT

Comment: @showrya yes two answer i provided so you can use upper btw your mysql version please

Comment: @showrya you can use use corelated subquery my 3rd answer

Answer (score 0):

You possibly want only those rows which are duplicate. If you don't have Window Functions available in your MySQL version, you can do the following:

```
SELECT
  t.* 
FROM your_table AS t 
JOIN (SELECT columnA, columnB 
      FROM your_table 
      GROUP BY columnA, columnB 
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS dt 
  ON dt.columnA = t.columnA AND dt.columnB = t.columnB
```

**Details:** In a [Derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), we get all those combination of `columnA` and `columnB` which have more than one row(s) (`HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`).

Now, we simply **join** this result-set back to the main table, to get those rows only.

**Note:** This approach would not be needed if you want to fetch only these two columns. A simple `Group By` with `Having` would suffice, as suggested in other answer(s). However, if you have more columns in the table, and you will need to fetch all of them, and not just the columns (used to determine duplicates); you will need to use this approach.

Comment: is it possible without COUNT

Comment: No, I'm solving a another problem - The shorter form reduces to above question.Is there a solution possible by not using COUNT

Comment: @showrya yes offcourse I could guess that. Please add more details to your question. I am pretty sure that you need to use Derived tables here, as you would have more columns in the table, and you will need to fetch all of them, not just the columns (used to determine) duplicates..

Comment: im working on a dB api(In a specific condition ) i need to display common values from two columns similar to above condition. It wouldbe really helpfull if i get result without using Count.

Comment: @showrya What is the problem with using `Count()` ? please be more specific. Do you have any primary key in the table ?

Comment: There's lot of similar files if i use count there will be other files. So is there a way to get the common values from two columns, So i could the same method for some other conditions.

Comment: @showrya can you please edit the question to add one such "similar file" case to the problem. Without looking at some sample data, it is hard to figure out what you are asking for!

Comment: @showrya I think I have already given an answer based on your current problem statement.

Comment: Could you please eloborate maybe with the (conditions/joins) in the WHERE condition.

Comment: @showrya Refer this link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html This will clarify the usage of a subquery in the from clause

Comment: Thank you for helping me, I'm a begginer in sql started a few days back.If  you could provide me a solution for above question that would be really helpfull. I haven't studied the group or count. So can you provide a simple solution(for now)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in` operator with a grouped subquery as :

```
select *
  from tab
 where ( columnA, columnB) in
  (
    select columnA, count(columnA) 
      from tab   
     group by columnA  
   );
```

or use a `self-join` as :

```
select t1.columnA, t1.columnB
  from tab t1
  join 
  (
    select columnA, count(columnA) as columnB
      from tab   
     group by columnA  
   ) t2
    on ( t1.columnA = t2.columnA and t1.columnB = t2.columnB );
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/AOWNM9007)

Comment: No, I'm solving a another problem - The shorter form reduces to above question.Is there a solution possible by not using COUNT or GROUPS

Answer (score 0):

I would use `EXISTS`, if the table has primary column :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table t1 WHERE t1.col1 = t.col1 AND t1.col2 = t.col2 AND t1.pk <> t.pk);
```

Comment: could you please eloborate, Im a beginner(regarding t, t1)

Comment: @showrya. . . `t` is outer query table reference & `t1` is inner query table reference.