# does mysql support intersect and minus set operator?

Tags: mysql

I'm getting an error when I'm using intersect or minus operator in MySQL. Help me with this. What is the alternative I can use instead of these operators?

select * from student_master;
intersect
select * from teacher_student_master;

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'intersect select * from teacher_student_master' at line 1  0.000 sec

Comment: There is not Intersect in MySql, you can do it whit an inner join

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INTERSECT in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300322/intersect-in-mysql)