# Filter data in table using MySQL by using similar clause as INTERSECT clause

Tags: mysql

[image]

By MYSQL, Filtering Products in table where Attribute_Value = "Jane Paul" AND Attribute_Value = "Diamond Publication".
This type of query should show result at Book_1 as it is only product where Attribute_Value is matching.
What MYSQL Query we can use for this?

Comment: What happens with the query? How is `PHP`, `MySQLi`, and `mysql-workbench` related?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [INTERSECT in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300322/intersect-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT Product 
FROM yourTable 
WHERE Product IN (SELECT Product FROM yourTable WHERE Attribute_value = 'Jane Paul') 
    AND Product IN (SELECT Product FROM yourTable WHERE Attribute_value = 'Diamond Publication')
```